# How to read CSV file into HashMap only for rows without blanks

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm performing a fairly unique CSV file reading but there is one unique aspect.  If the row has a blank cell value only in the 19th column, it is OK to go into the hashmap.  If any other column in the row has a blank cell, it should be excluded from the hashmap. The table has 22 total columns.  Is there any way to write this `if` statement without writing out each and every column index?  For example `if(piecesOfInfo[0] != "" && piecesOfInfo[1] != ""...)`

```
public HashMap<String,String[]> createHashMap() {
    File flightFile = new File("fying.csv");
    HashMap<String,String[]> flightsMap = new HashMap<String,String[]>();

    try {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(flightFile);
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String info = s.nextLine();
            String [] piecesOfInfo = info.split(",");
            if(/**piecesOfInfo contains no blanks aside from the 18th column**/){
            String flightKey = piecesOfInfo[4]; //Setting the Key
            String[] values = Arrays.copyOfRange(piecesOfInfo, 0, piecesOfInfo.length);

            flightsMap.put(flightKey, values);
            }
            }

    s.close();
    }


   catch (FileNotFoundException e)
   {
     System.out.println("Cannot open: " + flightFile);
   }

    return flightsMap;
}
```

Comment: You can use a loop over all indexes.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I will look into this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it the long way by listing out each column individually in the If statement:

```
    public HashMap<String,String[]> createHashMap() {
        File flightFile = new File("flights.csv");
        HashMap<String,String[]> flightsMap = new HashMap<String,String[]>();

        try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(flightFile);
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {

                String info = s.nextLine();
                String [] piecesOfInfo = info.split(",");
                if(piecesOfInfo[0] != "" || piecesOfInfo[1] != "" ||    piecesOfInfo[2] != "" ||    
                   piecesOfInfo[3] != "" ||     piecesOfInfo[4] != "" ||    piecesOfInfo[5] != "" ||    
                   piecesOfInfo[6] != "" ||     piecesOfInfo[7] != "" ||    piecesOfInfo[8] != "" ||    
                   piecesOfInfo[9] != "" ||     piecesOfInfo[10] != "" ||   piecesOfInfo[11] != "" ||   
                   piecesOfInfo[12] != "" ||    piecesOfInfo[13] != "" ||   piecesOfInfo[14] != "" ||   
                   piecesOfInfo[15] != "" ||    piecesOfInfo[16] != "" ||   piecesOfInfo[17] != "" ||   
                   piecesOfInfo[19] != "" ||    piecesOfInfo[20] != "" ||   piecesOfInfo[21] != "") {
                    String flightKey = piecesOfInfo[4] + "_" + piecesOfInfo[2] + "_" + piecesOfInfo[11]; //Setting the Key
                    String[] values = Arrays.copyOfRange(piecesOfInfo, 0, piecesOfInfo.length);

                    flightsMap.put(flightKey, values);
                }

        }
        s.close();
        }


       catch (FileNotFoundException e)
       {
         System.out.println("Cannot open: " + flightFile);
       }

        return flightsMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My be this will help:

```js
List infoList = Arrays.asList(piecesOfInfo);
if(!infoList.contains("") || (infoList.indexOf("")==18 && infoList.lastIndexOf("")==18) ){
// non empty piecesOfInfo expect position 19
}
```

Comment: @FinDev did you try my answer?